# Выполнение команды из файла

Tags: bash

Не могу понять, как заставить linux выполнить команду консоли, записаную в файл?
общая идея такая-мне нужно получить данные с помощью curl с сайта, я проанализировал запрос к сайту с помощью панели разработчика сохранил запрос в таком виде:

```
    curl 'url' \
  -H 'authority: www.url.ru' \
  -H 'accept: */*' \
  -H 'accept-language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7,fr;q=0.6,mt;q=0.5' \
  -H 'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8' \
  -H 'cookie: тут куки \
  -H 'dnt: 1' \
  -H 'origin: https://www.url.ru' \
  -H 'referer: https://www.url.ru/auth/' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua: "Not?A_Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="108", "Google Chrome";v="108"' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-dest: empty' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-mode: cors' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-site: same-origin' \
  -H 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36' \
  -H 'x-requested-with: XMLHttpRequest' \
  --data-raw 'form-id=form&tab-id=auth-tabpanel&backurl=43&timeout=2000&input=1&phone=2' \
  --compressed
```

Если данный кусок кода запускать из консоли, все отрабатывается верно.
НО мне нужно запускать его по cron  и получать информацию,я пытался сделать комбинацию
вида  bash <(curl localhost/1.txt) , в 1.txt я поместил эту команду, но в таком случае получается такая ошибка:

```
/dev/fd/63: line 2: -H: command not found
/dev/fd/63: line 3: -H: command not found
/dev/fd/63: line 4: -H: command not found
/dev/fd/63: line 5: -H: command not found
/dev/fd/63: line 6: -H: command not found
/dev/fd/63: line 7: -H: command not found
```

То есть командная строка берет из каждой строки по одной строчке и пытается выполнить
я уже пытался обрамить всю команду в кавычки, скобки, и тд, не получаеться, что я делаю не так?

Comment: 1. в шестой строке незакрытые одинарные кавычки. 2. собственно, отсутствует url, к которому должна обращаться программа curl. 3. окончания строк, случайно, не досовские? 4. ну и, да, ответ ответ black_paladin почти верен: биты исполняемости не нужны файлу при таком способе его использования.

Answer (score 0):

Сделайте исполняемый файл и запускайте его   `bash localhost/1.sh`

Comment: Тоже так делал, не выходит

Comment: Ваш вариант в консоли не работает. При удалении вложенных кавычек отрабатывает и в консоли и в файле.

Comment: Попробую, хорошо

Answer (score 0):

помогло установка преобразования конца строк в notepad++